# Cannot update user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm using `AspNetCore.Identity` for manage the user registered on my application. I have two tables:

- AspNetUsers: is created by default
- UserDetails: new table which contains extra information for each registered user

the `UserDetails` table contains an `FK` that point to `UserId` of `AspNetUsers`. The models are the following:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string LockoutMessage { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDetails UserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetails
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string FacebookLink { get; set; }
    public string TwitterLink { get; set; }
    public string SkypeLink { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

for update the database with these new field I did this:

```
add-migration MigrationName -context AppContext
update-database
```

and that works. Now I'm trying to update the current logged in user, so I created a method inside the `UserRepository` class which contains the following:

```
public UserProfileViewModel UpdateUserAsync(UserProfileViewModel updatedUser)
{
    var originalUser = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == updatedUser.Username);

    originalUser.FirstName = updatedUser.FirstName;
    originalUser.UserDetail = new UserDetails();
    originalUser.UserDetail.Biography = updatedUser.Biography;

    _db.SaveChanges();
    return updatedUser;
}
```

Essentially I send to this method the `ViewModel` of the form which contains the property to update, and then I search the user in the application context instance `_db` and updated all the fields.

The problem's come when the code reach `_db.SaveChanges()`, infact I get this error:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_UserDetails'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserDetails'.

I guess the code is trying to insert the field instead of update, and that is weird, someone could help me?

**UPDATE**

As you can see above I added extra field to the `AspNetUsers` table, for doing so I inherit `IdentityUser` from `User` class which I used to defined an entity here:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

the strange thing is that when I add a new record the `UserDetails` table is filled correctly, but when I need to update I guess `UserDetail` as null, and in the same time I cannot add another `UserDetail` because already exists and will generated a `CONSTRAINT` exception.

Comment: First off, why do you need a `User` property in `UserDetails`? You already reference `UserDetails` in `User`.

Comment: Can you comment this  and try //originalUser.UserDetail = new UserDetails();

Comment: @SainPradeep if I comment this, then `.UserDetail` will be null. And I added `User` in `UserDetails` for create the `FK` between the tables.

Comment: If you check closely your exception it says that "Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserDetails'." It means when you are creating UserDetails object with the new keyword then it try to insert the new userdetails in the database. Your select query should fill the userdetails object in place of the new keyword.

Comment: @SainPradeep so I guess I did some mistake in the tables `FK`, could you please show me the correct way to add another table with an `FK` of `AspNetUser`?

Comment: Do not create new UserDetails() if it is already exists. Cheeck if ( originalUser.UserDetail !=null)

Comment: @SergSh Okay I did this, but I get even null (the value for this user exists)

Comment: if ( originalUser.UserDetail ==null)  originalUser.UserDetail = new UserDetails(); have you done this ?

Comment: @SergSh yep I did exactly this, but the `originalUser` contains as `.UserDetail` a null object

Comment: you need to do extra 
if ( originalUser.UserDetail ==null){originalUser.UserDetail = new UserDetails(); originalUser.UserDetail.User = originalUser;} to link both objects

Comment: @KirkLarkin okay, thanks but I got this error now: `The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.` this happen when the code reach this line: `await _userManager.UpdateAsync(originalUser);`

Comment: For the moment I fixed with: await `_db.SaveChangesAsync();` so I guess I need to use the database context instance instead of usermanager, unfortunately some method like the password hashing are available only in the user manager, is not possible to use only the db instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework Core does not load related data unless you instruct it do so using one of a few options, all of which are documented in [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/related-data). When you run the following query against the `DbSet`:

```
_db.Users
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == updatedUser.Username);
```

The value for the `UserDetail` navigation property is not populated. In order to work around that, you can use the following modification:

```
_db.Users
    .Include(u => u.UserDetail)
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == updatedUser.Username);
```

As you've indicated in the comments on the OP itself, this introduces a new error, in that combining this approach with `_userManager.UpdateUserAsync` is complaining that the `User` is already being tracked. Also in the comments, you've asked the following question:

> For the moment I fixed with: `await _db.SaveChangesAsync()`; so I guess I need to use the database context instance instead of usermanager, unfortunately some method like the password hashing are available only in the user manager, is not possible to use only the db instance?

In order to achieve the desired result here, you should be able to use something like this:

```
public async Task<UserProfileViewModel> UpdateUserAsync(UserProfileViewModel updatedUser)
{
    var originalUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(updatedUser.Username);

    // This is the "magic" (ok, it's a bit of a hack).
    _db.Entry(originalUser).Reference(u => u.UserDetail).Load();

    ...

    await _userManager.UpdateUserAsync(originalUser);
    return updatedUser;
}
```

This specific approach was suggested in a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1509) and is essentially just another way to load related data (as documented in the link I provided).

Note: I've converted your `UpdateUserAsync` function to use `async/await` in order to use the `UserManager` functions.